# What is the scope of imports defined in the package __init__.py file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

For a project I had to switch from C++ to python but I'm having some trouble fully understanding the `__init__.py` file. I found the following documentation on the `__init__.py` file:

- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html
- https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-create-a-python-package/
- http://mikegrouchy.com/blog/2012/05/be-pythonic-__init__py.html

To get more familiar with the way the `__init__.py` file works I did some tests in both python 2.7 and 3.6.5. I used the "PythonCentral" test pacakge (see link 2) for this:

[image: package overview]

Now I understand the following about the `__init__.py` file:

- The `__init__.py` file executes when a module or subpackage module is imported.
- The `__init__.py` can be used to overload the package `__all__` method.
- The `__init__.py` can be used to define the import order
- The `__init__.py` can be used to make classes available on package and subpackage level.

Using the different modules and classes from the scope of my main file seems to go as explained in the documentation. However when trying to use a class that is defined in another subpackage module I run into troubles. In python 2.7 created the following `__init__.py` file in the subanimals subpackage:

```
from Mammals import Mammals

print "subpackage __init__.py executed"
```

Following I created the following code inside the Bird.py module:

```
class Birds:
    def __init__(self):
        ''' Constructor for this class. '''
        # Create some member animals
        self.members = ['Sparrow', 'Robin', 'Duck']


    def printMembers(self):
        print('Printing members of the Birds class')
        for member in self.members:
           print('\t%s ' % member)

        test = Mammals()
        test.printMembers
```

When running the main following main script:

```
    from animals.subanimals import Birds

test = Birds()
test.printMembers()
```

I keep getting the global name Mammals not defined. I can solve this in python 2.7 by adding from Mammals import Mammals to the top of the Birds.py.

Does the `__init__.py` only import packages and classes on the scope level of the main script and therefore not inside the Birds.py module or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: Each individual file must be valid on its own, defining all appropriate imports. `__init__.py` is for aggregating multiple files in a directory into a single module; think of it as grouping and passing attributes *up* to the parent, not *down* to the other files in that directory.

Comment: I don't see where you are importing Mammals, add from Mammals import Mammals into Birds.py, also please avoid naming file the same way into subdirs, this just adds confusion and unwanted behaviors.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ah So if I understand you correctly the __init__.py file is only for the functions I described above and can not be used in a similar way as C++ header files are used? In python I therfore have to define all my imports in all my py files?

Comment: @simoneZandara Yea I tried that and that solved the error but I was wondering if it was possible to use the \__init\__.py as some kind of header file (equivalent to C++) in which i can specify all my package imports. Judging from your and jonrscharpe 's comment it looks that that is not possible.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Also thanks a lot for enhancing the formatting of my question I will use your style in other questions I ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to my question can be found in @jonrsharpe 's comment.

> Each individual file must be valid on its own, defining all
>   appropriate imports. **init**.py is for aggregating multiple files in
>   a directory into a single module; think of it as grouping and passing
>   attributes up to the parent, not down to the other files in that
>   directory.